# crontab with config not working magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4.4

im working on cron with config path to schedule according to expression set from admin, value getting saved in db after save configuration but cron not working nor showing in **cron_schedule** table.

> here is my config in admin
> [image]

> here is my system.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="autoordercancel_config" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Order Cancel</label>
            <tab>vendor_module</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::conf</resource>
            <group id="cancelorder_cron" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Cron Settings</label>
                <field id="frequency" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Frequency</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Source\Frequency</source_model>
                    <backend_model>Custom\AutoOrderCancel\Model\Config\CronConfig</backend_model>
                </field>
                <field id="time" translate="label comment" sortOrder="2" type="time" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Start Time</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> here is my crontab.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="index">
        <job instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\CancelOrder" method="execute" name="custom_autoordercancel_cron">
            <config_path>crontab/default/jobs/custom_autoordercancel_cron/schedule/cron_expr</config_path>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

> here is my CronConfig.php

```
<?php

 
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config;
 
class CronConfig extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{
    /**
     * Cron string path
     */
    const CRON_STRING_PATH = 'crontab/default/jobs/custom_autoordercancel_cron/schedule/cron_expr';
 
    /**
     * Cron model path
     */
    const CRON_MODEL_PATH = 'crontab/default/jobs/custom_autoordercancel_cron/run/model';
 
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory
     */
    protected $_configValueFactory;
 
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_runModelPath = '';
 
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory $configValueFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param string $runModelPath
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory $configValueFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        $runModelPath = '',
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_runModelPath = $runModelPath;
        $this->_configValueFactory = $configValueFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
 
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function afterSave()
    {
        $time = $this->getData('groups/cancelorder_cron/fields/time/value');
        $frequency = $this->getData('groups/cancelorder_cron/fields/frequency/value');
 
        $cronExprArray = [
            intval($time[1]), //Minute
            intval($time[0]), //Hour
            $frequency == \Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Source\Frequency::CRON_MONTHLY ? '1' : '*', //Day of the Month
            '*', //Month of the Year
            $frequency == \Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Source\Frequency::CRON_WEEKLY ? '1' : '*', //Day of the Week
        ];
 
        $cronExprString = join(' ', $cronExprArray);
 
        try {
            $this->_configValueFactory->create()->load(
                self::CRON_STRING_PATH,
                'path'
            )->setValue(
                $cronExprString
            )->setPath(
                self::CRON_STRING_PATH
            )->save();
            $this->_configValueFactory->create()->load(
                self::CRON_MODEL_PATH,
                'path'
            )->setValue(
                $this->_runModelPath
            )->setPath(
                self::CRON_MODEL_PATH
            )->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception(__('We can\'t save the cron expression.'));
        }
 
        return parent::afterSave();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not shared code of remaining files of your module. Could you please share that as well?

Comment: also module and routes.xml remaing and cant paste helper code here

Comment: No Issues, just add skeleton of *Vendor\Module\Cron\CancelOrder* class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe broken because  Cache.
Try to run with manually.

```
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento cron:remove
bin/magento cron:install
bin/magento cron:run --group index
```

Let's check your job name (custom_autoordercancel_cron) in the **job_code.cron_schedule** db and check the Status.

Comment: already tried this but no success.

Comment: Are you check Cron.log file ?

Comment: yes no traces there